# Reemplazar un carácter por un guion mientras sea distinto de un espacio en blanco

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al hacer el juego del ahorcado(verdugo). Resulta que quiero reemplazar un carácter de un String por guiones, pero cuando haya un espacio dejar dicho espacio en el nuevo String.

En python es algo asi:

```
for caracter in palabra:
  if (caracter != " "):
```

pero en java no se como hacerlo

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar `str.replaceAll()` que toma expresiones regulares, en este caso "todoloquenoseaespacio" quedaría algo asi:

```
String palabraconguiones = palabra.replaceAll("[^ ]", "-");
```

LLevado al juego del ahorcado incluis las letras que ya están descubiertas 
ejemplo: A, F, X y T

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String palabra = "TNETENNBA";
    String frase = "Thats A Nice Tnetennba";
    String letraselegidas = "AFXT";

    String palabraconguiones = palabra.replaceAll("[^ "+letraselegidas+"]", "-");
    String fraseconguiones = frase.replaceAll("[^ "+letraselegidas.toLowerCase()+letraselegidas+"]", "-");

    System.out.println("elige otra letra: "+ palabraconguiones);
    System.out.println("frase de ejemplo: "+ fraseconguiones);
  }
}
```

---

```
elige otra letra: T--T----A
frase de ejemplo: T-at- A ---- T--t----a
```

Comment: Perfecto. Sin querer me resolviste el 95% del juego, muchas gracias!!